# Replacing Python 2.7.5 with Python 3.4 on OS X 10.9.2

Tags: python

I have Python 2.7.5 running on OS X 10.9.2.

I downloaded the Python installer "python-3.4.0-macosx10.6.dmg" from python.org.

After the installation, I still get 2.7.5 when querying `python -V`.

I am not sure what I need to do to replace 2.7.5 with 3.4 besides installing python-3.4.0-macosx10.6.dmg.

Comment: I simply replaced the executable link in my IDE from "/usr/bin/python" to "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin".

Comment: are you running it on a virtual environment? I would strongly advise against switching the OS version as the OS uses 2.7.5 and switching would break stuff

Comment: No. I'm running it on my actual mac os. But from what you're saying, since 2.7.5 is still in /usr/bin, that should be ok?

Comment: yeah you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I simply replaced the executable link in my IDE from "/usr/bin/python" to "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin".